# config file for Arduino Uno installed on Raspberry PI

Tags: arduino-uno, raspberrypi

The Arduino code shown runs successfully. My problem is configuring the Arduino IDE so it fits within the Raspberry Pi window. The second image, the built-in serial port /dev/ttyAMA0, is produced. It is blank.

The Arduino Menu bar cannot be accessed. Therefore, the **Tools** button and other buttons for running the code are not available. The user can adjust the width of the Arduino IDE window but cannot move it around the screen or up or down.

The /boot/config file is setup up for a Adafruit 5" Backback monitor. No other app, Thonny Pi, or the terminal has these problems.

It appears to me that the config file needs some work. That is only a guess.

```
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.
```

[image: Arduino Window is too big for the Raspberry Pi screen.]

Comment: Please edit the post to remove non-code text from code tags

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you can move things around in different ways. For example:

1. Hold ALT and click and drag anywhere in the window. The whole window will move and you can get to the edge to resize it.
2. Press ALT-Space then M and you can use the cursor keys to move the window around
3. Press ALT-Space then X and it will maximise the window to the screen size

Comment: Thank you. The command key works.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set the default IDE window size by editing preferences.txt:

Click the link on the line following File > Preferences > More preferences can be edited directly in the file.

This will open the Arduino15 (or similar folder name) folder.

Close the Arduino IDE.

Open the file preferences.txt in a text editor

Change the editor.window.height.default and editor.window.width.default properties to your desired window size.

Save the file.